# Need help in understanding this code

Tags: c

There some code in one gstreamer-plugin:

```
static GstFlowReturn
gst_ebml_peek_id_full (GstEbmlRead * ebml, guint32 * id, guint64 * length,
    guint * prefix)
{
  GstFlowReturn ret;

  ret = gst_ebml_peek_id_length (id, length, prefix,
      (GstPeekData) gst_ebml_read_peek, (gpointer) gst_ebml_read_br (ebml),
      ebml->el, gst_ebml_read_get_pos (ebml));
  if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK)
    return ret;

  GST_LOG_OBJECT (ebml->el, "id 0x%x at offset 0x%" G_GINT64_MODIFIER "x"
      " of length %" G_GUINT64_FORMAT ", prefix %d", *id,
      gst_ebml_read_get_pos (ebml), *length, *prefix);
```

Now see the 4:th argument to `gst_ebml_peek_id_length ()` is

```
(GstPeekData) gst_ebml_read_peek
```

where `gst_ebml_read_peek` is another function whose definition is:

```
static const guint8 *
gst_ebml_read_peek (GstByteReader * br, guint peek)
{
  const guint8 *data = NULL;

  if (G_LIKELY (gst_byte_reader_peek_data (br, peek, &data)))
    return data;
  else
    return NULL;
}
```

Now I want to ask you is: `gst_ebml_read_peek` has two input argument in definition, so how can it be called (in the upper code) without arguments?

Edit: 
You can find this code at
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/coverage/lcov/gst-plugins-good/gst/matroska/ebml-read.c.gcov.html

From around line 194.

Comment: N.B. There's a comma between `gst_ebml_read_peek` and `(gpointer)`.

Comment: The person who wrote this code should be taken outside and shot. But I will endevour to help you.

Comment: Giving us such code without the corresponding data types is not very usefull. If `GstPeekData` is a `typedef` of an object type casting a function pointer with it is UB. gcc usually accepts such things, but this is not portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler example doing a similar thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*binaryop)(int, int);

static int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

static int mul(int a, int b) {
  return a * b;
}

static void print_result(binaryop op, int a, int b) {
  printf("%d\n", op(a, b));
}

int main() {
  print_result(add, 2, 3);
  print_result(mul, 5, 7);
  return 0;
}
```

The `print_result` function takes *another function* as a parameter, which it then calls. When you just write `add` without the parentheses, the function is not yet called. It is only called in a *function call expression*, and that looks like this: `function_name(arguments)`.

Comment: i am accepting ur answer because your example has helped me lot to understand this.. thnk you

Comment: whats the benefit of doing such things?

Comment: It can be used to write modular code. For example, there may be a generic sorting function `qsort` that can sort *anything*. To do that it relies on a *comparator function* that compares two items. Depending on which function you pass in, you can compare arbitrary objects without having to write your sort function again.

Answer (score 8):

Because it's a [function pointer](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html). The function is not actually called at that point, it's just passed to `gst_ebml_peek_id_length` (which will likely call it later with the correct arguments).

Comment: Worth noting is that `GstPeekData` is probably a `typedef` for `const guint8 *(*)(GstByteReader  *, guint)`

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev That's very probable, thanks for the comment.

Comment: whats the benefit of doing such things?

Answer (score 1):

Argument passed to gst_ebml_peek_id_full() is function pointer of gst_ebml_read_peek() or in other terms its just passing the handle of the function so that gst_ebml_peek_id_full() can call passed in function with correct parameter.

Gives flexibility of passing your own/different implementation of function which implements same prototype of gst_ebml_read_peek().